# How do I query DynamoDB without specifying a partition key value?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a simple table consisting of orderID as PK and userID as SK, I found out that in dynamoDB you need to specify both PK and SK to use query. so in this case, how is it possible for me to get all the orders for userID x since I can't ignore orderID since they're the partition key of this table? another way to solve this which works but not recomended is using a scan filter, which scans the whole table then filters the result. it will eventually slow down as the table grow. I wonder how do you guys do it with this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) based on userId and query based on that index.

You can read more about indexes and GSI’s in the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html).